# Why does this regex not work?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to grab any data between these two div headers, and the code below should work, is there something I am not seeing?

```
preg_match_all('$\<div class\=\"productDescriptionWrapper\"\>(.*?)\<div class\=\"emptyClear\"\>$', $source, $match);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: O GOD IT'S TERRIBLE. sorry. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You have to start with `^` to indicate start of the string. `$` should be used to indicate end of the string. Also, question mark after * seems to be awkward.

Comment: "I think that using a regular expression to process XML when there are plenty of good XML parsers out there is a bad idea."

Comment: I explained exactly what was needed, what is not clear about 'grab any data between two div headers'?

Comment: Show us some sample data that this regex is supposed to work on. It works fine as long as the data matches the regex: http://rubular.com/r/FOhXe2Us9n Also, use an XML parser!

Comment: @user482594 that question mark means non-greedy matching. It's not at all "awkward".

Comment: Also the dollar symbols are to mark the beginning and end of the regex. Normally you'd see a `/` here, but for reasons I don't fully grasp the OP decided to use dollar signs.

Comment: In fact, "awkward" is a good word for *that* (i.e., using `$` as the regex delimiter).  But I wouldn't use `/` either; it's too common in HTML.  Also, `<`, `>`, `=` and `"` have no special meaning in regexes, so none of those backslashes are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Cory, typically you should be using DOMDocument to do this. Using regex to parse html is not considered good practice because it contains so many hidden follies and overcomplicates.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php